# Any OData filter operator/function for: where property in list of values?

Tags: java, .net, servlets, odata, olingo

How can this SQL be written in OData?

```
 select * from Employees where department in ('Engineering', 'Human Resources', 'Management');
```

I wonder if there is some operator/function for that. Something like this:

```
/Employees?$filter=department in ('x', 'y', 'z')
```

**Note:** I am trying to avoid supporting OR operator in my application. (moreover, it is not practical with large number of values)

Answer (score 0):

OData v4 does not have a special operator for checking a string value for membership in a list of strings. Your only practical choice is the `or` operator.